# An MVC 6 route does not perform as expected

Tags: asp.net-mvc, actionresult, maproute

I have this route:

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "Trads",
    url: "test_3000/{action}/{traditional}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Test_3000", action = "Subset", traditional = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

And a Test_3000Controller with this method:

```
    // GET: Test_3000/Subset?traditional=(Chinese Character)
public ActionResult Subset(string traditional)
{
    if (traditional == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Test_3000 test_3000 = db.Test_3000.Find(traditional);
    if (test_3000 == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(test_3000);
}
```

This URL works:

> server/test_3000/subset?traditional=的

This URL does NOT work:

> server/test_3000/subset/的

In the latter case, 'traditional' is null.

"Traditional" is a column in an SQL table.

Comment: Is this the first route definition (before the default)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this

```
Routes.MapRoute(name: "Trads",
    url: "test_3000/{action}/{traditional?}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Test_3000", action = "Subset", traditional = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Notice the **?** on traditional.
Also

```
public ActionResult Subset(string traditional  = null)
{ ... }
```

So that traditional is explicitly set as an optional

Comment: OP already has `traditional = UrlParameter.Optional`. And `string` is already `null` by default (none of this is required)

Comment: And adding the `?` will throw an exception - _The route URL cannot start with a '/' or '~' character and it cannot contain a '?' character_. That is only applicable to attribute routing

Comment: No, I haven't tried this version, but it seems I don't want to. No?

Answer (score 0):

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "ChBoPinCritCji",
            url: "charbopopincrits/subset/{Char}",
            defaults: new { controller = "CharBopoPinCrits", action = "Subset", Char = typeof(string) }
        );
```

This MapRoute, which is first, now works.

Thanks for the attention.